# Is the following sentence a parallel structure?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

> I bought not only a Christmas tree but also lots of presents.

The key for the exercises marks the sentence as a parallel structure, though I think it is not.

To be a parallel structure, the parts after the connectors should have the same forms. Considering the connector as **not only... but also...**, I don't see **a Christmas tree** and **lots of presents** as having the same form.

Am I wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "same form"? ***a Christmas tree*** has the form **DETERMINER** ('a') **+ NOUN** ('Christmas tree'). ***lots of presents*** has the same form **DETERMINER** ('lots of') **+ NOUN** ('presents'). It depends on how strictly you interpret "same" and the level of granularity of "form".

Comment: So my mistake was classifying **a** as a definite article instead of a determiner. Thank you, Mr. @Silenius.

Comment: "indefinite article", not "definite".

Comment: Thank you for pointing another mistake of mine! I did a google search now and realized that an indefinite article is a determiner. So my mistake was nor considering the "lots of" as a determiner.

Comment: @Silenus. "Lots of" is not a determiner. "Lots" is a quantificational noun taking an _of_ preposition phrase as complement.

Comment: @Franks T. Maia Your sentence is fine, The coordinates are structurally alike (parallel) in that they are both noun phrases. What makes you think they are not parallel?

Comment: @BillJ, the syntax of "determiners" is a (very) vexed issue in syntax. Probably always will be. Suffice it to say that many treat "lots of" as a quantifier and hence determiner. Here's an example of it being called a quantifier: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/much-many-a-lot-of-lots-of-quantifiers. Also, there's nothing wrong with determiners being composed of nouns (for example "lots"). For example, "The dog's" is a complex determiner composed of a definite article, the noun "dog" and a possessive -'s', or "John's".

Comment: I'm not aware of it being a vexed issue. Here, "lots" is a quantificational noun as head with an _of_ PP as complement; at word-level "lots" and "of" are separate constituents (noun head + prep as part of complement).The "lots" in "lots of presents" is a number-transparent noun in that the number of the noun in the PP complement (i.e."presents") determines the verb agreement: "Lots of presents were received". Cf. "Lots of work was done".

Comment: @BillJ, thank you for your comment. What made me confused was looking at the syntax structure of the noun phrases, instead of considering them as NP and went ahead. I was expecting a indefinite article after **but also...**, so it could be "perfectly" parallel with goes after **not only...*. I shouldn't be so strict, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I bought not only a Christmas tree but also lots of presents.

What did you buy?

"bought" is a transitive verb that takes an object

I bought a Christmas tree. [*tree* = **noun** = direct object]

I bought lots of presents. [*lots* = plural **noun** = direct object]

See Definition 5:

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lot

Parallelism is achieved with the direct objects being of the same form: nouns

I bought *not only* a Christmas **tree** *but also* **lots** of presents. (noun/noun) *NOTE: It doesn't matter if one noun object is singular and the other plural; they are still of the same form: a noun.*

I / bought / not only / a / Christmas / tree / but also / lots / of presents

Subject, pronoun / verb / conjunction / article / adjective / noun / conjunction / plural noun / adjective prepositional phrase that is modifying "lots" to describe, as an adjective would, "What kind? "Lots of what kind of things?" Presents

> 16a. Express parallel ideas in same grammatical form. Coordinate equal
>   rank and connected by *and, but, or, nor*, or:
>
> 16b. Place correlative conjunctions immediately before the parallel
>   terms (both..and, either...or, neither...nor, not only...but also)

John E. Warriner. Warriner’s English Grammar and Composition. Fifth Course. Liberty Edition. Orlando, Florida: Harcourt, Brace, and Jovanovich. 1986. 303-08.

Answer (score 2):

The 'similarity' required to license the *not only .. but also* construction is that both entities serve the same syntactic role. In your sentence both *a Christmas tree* and *lots of presents* are NPs (in fact they are both actual 'noun phrases') serving as objects of *bought*.

You may in fact employ this construction with much more dissimilar entities:

> I bought not only a Christmas tree but also whatever the lot offered which I could twist into a collection of handsome Christmas wreaths for the walls.

Comment: I think you'll need a *that* after *offered* to prevent readers from taking the non-parallel garden path.

Comment: @deadrat I hope you'll settle for which: I have a longstanding aversion to relative *that* when it can be avoided.

Comment: Based on Strunk and White, I support @deadrat. He's obviously a practiced "which" hunter.

Comment: @RichardKayser That *which* which that *that* replaced is fine with me. I just wanted to avoid the parse *Whatever the lot offered, I could twist into a collection....*

Comment: @deadrat Shouldn't it be "That *which* that that *that* replaced is fine with me"? Record number of consecutive properly-used *that*s?

Comment: @RichardKayser Really! That's the limit! Or do I mean *that*'s the limit?